# how to clear out dom form data when removing a view that will be reused later

Tags: jquery, forms, dom

I am having an issue with form data from previous views persisting, and then when the view is called again that persisted data is muddying the information the user is trying to send. For example on app load I have a login view. when the user submits the username and password I remove the view from the parent, and load up the main app. when the user logs out I clear out my model and rebuild the login view. when the user clicks the submit button (no form) the dom is showing 2 sets of user login data. Does anyone have suggestions on how with jquery to clear form data from the dom?

I a using jquery with bootstraps, and using brite.js as my mvc framework.

here is my login form

```
<div id="loginForm" data-b-view="Login" data-brite-cid="bview_37">
    <div class="border shadow rounded text-center" style="margin: 0 auto !important;width:750px;">
      <div class="holder lText">
        <h2>Welcome to dmEDGE5!</h2>
        <div class="span7">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. </div>
        <div class="span7">
          <div class="row">
            <span>Username: </span>
            <input id="loginUser" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>Password: </span>
            <input id="loginPass" type="password">
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <span>Remember me on this computer </span>
            <input id="loginRemember" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button id="loginSubmitBtn" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Login!</button>
          </div>
          <p class="cText"><span id="forgotPass" class="link">Forgot Password</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="createAcct" class="link">Create Account</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>      
  </div>
```

now here is my jquery listener and resulting functions

```
$('#loginSubmitBtn').click(function() {
var user = $('#loginUser').val();
var pass = $('#loginPass').val();
if ($('#loginRemember').is(":checked")){
    localStorage.Username = user;
}else{
    localStorage.Username = '';
}
loginUser(user, pass)
});

function loginUser(user, pass){
  if (user.length > 1 || pass.length > 1 ){
    location.hash = '#/authenticateUser';
    authUser(user, pass);
  } else {
      alert('Your username or password is incorrect please try again.');
      location.hash = '#/login';
  }
}

function authUser(user, pass){
  var url = modelLocator.httpServiceRoot + 'j_spring_security_check';
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: {
        j_username : user,
        j_password : pass
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        loginSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)},
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        loginError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)},
      timeout: function(){ loginTimeout() },
      scriptCharset: 'UTF-8',
      dataType: 'xml'
    });
}
```

Also if the user incorrectly logins in and then correctly logs in it will log in twice. first with the bad credentials and then with the correct credentials.

so bottom line is how do i clear out the info in te dom after the user clicks the button.

Also using $('#loginForm input').val(''); doesn't work if I do this jquery submits '' even if the user enters data.

It was suggested to use a set of form tags to take advantage of .reset(), however we saw this cause the bug in IE where clicking on the button causes the page to reload and affects the hashchange. In firefox and chrome I saw data double submit. there is one click listener so not sure why it double fires. Also as I mentioned we are using an mvc framework in conjunction with handlebars and bootstraps to dynamically build the pages based on data coming from the server. So the flow of the page rendering is

- App Loads up
- Based on the hash in the url we use the mvc to call the views controller (in this case the login view)
- The controller makes all the data calls and pushes the data in to the model. Then sends a render request to the mvc and handlebars.
- Handle bars loops through the template and returns the finished html
- the view is made visible to the user

What I am seeing happen is the first time you login its fine. then when you log out and log back in it makes all the calls twice. then if you log out again and the third login makes all the calls three times.

I have tried $('divID input').val('') and $('divID input').val(null) however when the user enters a value it is showing as either '' or null.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$('#loginForm').reset()`, but you need to use an actual form, not a DIV.

Comment: changing the id'd div to a form causes inter browser performance issues. IE reloads the screen on it self. I am using hash changes to change views and clicking a button in the form on IE makes the page reload. Also in FF and chrome I am getting double submits when changing to a form on the initial submit. I am not sure if this is being caused by brite or handlebars on how the page is rendering. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you please explain these performance issue when using a form tag?